# Using statement if in looping ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, if-statement

Maybe friends here consider me not doing my own business, or googling research. But I am asking a question here because indeed I feel deadlocked, which is why this forum is said to be stack overflow.

I want to use a statement on data looping done on ajax, but I have a problem.

Error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token if

The syntax below is what I made, if this is indeed wrong please help me fix it.

```
      $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url : '<?php echo base_url() ?>index.php/truk/daftar_jeniskerusakan_ajx',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success:function(data){
          var i = 1;
          var html;
          for (x=0; x<data.length;x++) {
            html += "<tr>"+
                    "<td>"+i+"</td>"+
                    "<td>"+data[x].jenis_kerusakan+"</td>"+
                    if(data[x].status === "1"){
                    "<td>"+"&nbsp;"+"</td>"+
                    }else{                          
                    "<td>"+"<a href='' class='btn btn-xs btn-success'>Approve</a>"+"</td>"+
                    };
                    "</tr>";
                  i++;
          }
          $('#daftar_jenis_kerusakan').append(html);
          $('#daftar_jenis_kerusakan').DataTable({
            "pageLength" : 10,
            "dom" : '<"search"f><"top">rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">'
          });
        }
      });
```

Comment: You can't use if/else in a string (HTML markup) that chained with "+". Use ternary condition instead. If you can't figured out tell me to make an answer

Comment: I don't know if a statement like that can't be done just like that, because he was in javascript scope so I just entered it, now I understand, thank you very much.

Comment: Because most cases that carry out statements only in the response are not on certain lines in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect with your string *concatenation*. You are essentially telling javascript to append an `if` statement to a string which doesn't make sense, as the if statement is supposed to evaluate conditions (and isn't a type of data). Instead, you need to use the if statement to append to the current value of `html` like so:

```
var i = 1;
var html;
for (x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
  html += "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + i + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + data[x].jenis_kerusakan + "</td>";

  if (data[x].status === "1") {
    html += "<td>" + "&nbsp;" + "</td>";
  } else {
    html += "<td>" + "<a href='' class='btn btn-xs btn-success'>Approve</a>" + "</td>";
  }

  html += "</tr>";
  i++;
}
```

Comment: I think the statement like I did can be done just like that because it was in the scope of javascript. I now understand, thank you friends for helping me, this works well.

Answer (score 0):

If statements are not allowed in that context. You could opt for a ternerary operator

```
"some string"+(data[x].status === "1"?"true case":"false case")+"some more strings"
```

Or you outsource the logic to a function that returns a string

```
var conditionalString = (someVar) => {
    if(someVar === "1"){
        return "<td>"+"&nbsp;"+"</td>"
    }else{
        return "<td>"+"<a href='' class='btn btn-xs btn-success'>Approve</a>"+"</td>"
    }
}
```

and then

```
"some string"+conditionalString(data[x].status)+"some more strings"
```

You can also opt to define the function in-line, but I'll leave figuring that syntax out to yourself.

Comment: Thank you for helping, I've got enlightenment.